# how to detect incoming chat message?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chat, ajax-polling

I'm using PHP, AJAX, a MySQL database, and a lot of jQuery to prototype web-based chat system (similar to Facebook Chat). I'm stuck on how to "listen" for incoming chats... when to know someone is trying to chat me... and to know that it is a new chat, not an existing chat.

Right now, I'm polling to see if there has been new insertions in the database tables but it seems very inefficient... a lot of overhead for the server.

Is there a way to receive a notification when, for example, a row has been inserted in a table in a MySQL database so that instead of having constantly poll, I can just be notified and then go look at what as inserted?

If there is a better and more efficient way to create this one-on-one chat relationship, please give me some suggestions.

Thanks, Hristo

Comment: You can use the ajax to keep checking your entries every X seconds... if an entry with higher id then the last message you got is entered then you either open a new window with the new user in the chat or print it on the given open window that depends on how your chat works and how your database struct is ... and if u want something like a messenger or a plain multi user chat.

Comment: ahhh.. higher id... good point, I didn't think about that. I was going off of timestamp, but that is hard to deal with. Thanks I'll try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use polling, but you can use a technique called Comet which involves long-polling, i.e. sending out an ajax request that will be held by the server until a chat request comes in.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Comment: This is like the 5th time I've heard about Comet... probably time for me to check it out. Thanks. Can you give me some more specifics on the logic behind Comet?

Comment: @hristo, Comet isn't a specific technology. It's the name given to any technique to simulate pushing data over the web. It's as much a technology as Ajax is.

Comment: +1 Hadn't heard the term before - sounds useful. This may be of use: http://www.dashdashverbose.com/2010/02/nodejs-websockets-stoopid-easy-comet.html

Answer (score 1):

I think polling is the only way for JavaScript to be pushed server side changes.